# Testing a function that is being created inside of a switch statement

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to test `testONE` and `testTWO` in this scenario. I have tried mocking with `jest.fn()` but could not get it to run. I also need to pass parameters to the functions inside the switch cases are being declared inside each switch case.

**testfile.js**

```js
exports.handler = testFunction(async (p1,p2,p3) { 
switch(p2) {
case '1':
function testONE(p1,p2) {
//function logic
}
break;
case '2':
function testTWO(p1,p2){
//function logic
}
}
break;
//rest of code
```

**testfile.spec.js**

```
const testFunction = require('**PATH**)();
 it( 'switch case -  '1' ',async ()=>{
    const spy = jest.spyOn(testFunction, 'testONE');
    await testFunction(1,'1',1);
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
   }
```

Error Log

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'property' of undefined

      101 |       function testONE(p1, p2) {         
    > 103 |         if (p2.property) {
```

Comment: What does the error stack say?

Comment: I added my error logs. I cannot set the parameters. @ckesplin